# How to deal with REST API calls in a multi-tenant application frontend in React?

Tags: reactjs, rest, frontend, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application separated in frontend(React) and backend(REST API made in Node.js). Each user can have their own subdomain, such as `alice.example.com` or `bob.example.com`, where the tenant is the first part of the URL. Each one of those custom pages have their own theme(just a primary color and a logo). You can access the API for a specific tenant through `bob.example.com/api/v1`, for example.

So far so good. But the problem is: How to deal with this in the frontend? When someone enters `bob.example.com` how will the React application know which specific theme to load from backend and make API calls only to `bob.example.com/api/v1`? Is it ok to make an API call everytime my page reloads to get theme colors and images? If so, how to get the tenant in frontend since React Router doesn't deals with subdomains?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can store colors value in redux specific to users. So that when ever you reload or when ever different user try to use the page then w.r.t user color theme can be shown. 
Thankyou